# How to show table content based on the foreignId in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have a table called **pekerjaan (work)** and it is in an eloquent with another table called **jeniskerja (type of work)**, jeniskerja hasMany pekerjaan, and pekerjaan belongsTo jeniskerja... **I want to show the list of the work based on the type of the work which is the foreignId when the user click on the type shown below (if the type is A it will show list of works of type A)**, but the problem is I already shown the table based on another foreignId, in this case it is the penyedia (vendor)... So, at the moment the table in foreach section show all the list of works based on the penyedia_id (vendor_id)... **How do I create another filter whereby when the user click on the type (in this case a card header) it will expand and show the list of works table based on the type they are clicking?**

Here is what my code looks like:

**AdminController**

```
public function showpenyedia(Penyedia $penyedia){
        $pekerjaan = $penyedia->pekerjaans; //show pekerjaan(work) based on penyedia(vendor)

        $jeniskerja = Jeniskerja::all();
        
        return view('admin.showpenyedia', compact('penyedia','pekerjaan','jeniskerja'));
    }
```

**detailpenyedia.php** (this is where the table content is)

```
@foreach ($jeniskerja as $jeniskerjas)
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card card-default collapsed-card">
      <div class="card-header collapsed-card">
        <h3 class="card-title">
          <b>{{$jeniskerjas->nama_jenis}}</b> //show the name of the type
        </h3>
    
        <div class="card-tools">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body table-responsive">
        <table id="tabelpekerjaan" class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 10px" rowspan="2">Tahun Anggaran</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Tanggal Kontrak</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Paket Pekerjaan</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Nama Perusahaan</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Lokasi Pekerjaan</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Jenis Pekerjaan</th>
              <th rowspan="2">HPS</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Nilai</th>
              <th rowspan="2">Dokumen</th>
              <th colspan="2">Tanggal</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Tgl Buat</td>
              <td>Tgl Update</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @php $no = 1; /*$totalNilai = 0.0;*/ @endphp
            @foreach ($pekerjaan as $pekerjaans)
            <tr>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->tanggal->format('Y')}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->tanggal->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->pekerjaan}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->penyedia->nama}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->lokasi}}</td>
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->jeniskerja->nama_jenis}}</td>
              <td>Rp. {{number_format($pekerjaans->hps,0,',',',')}}</td>
              @php
              $pekerjaans->nilai_total = $pekerjaans->nilai_1 + $pekerjaans->nilai_2 + $pekerjaans->nilai_3 + $pekerjaans->nilai_4;
              @endphp
              <td>{{$pekerjaans->nilai_total}}</td>
              <td><a href="{{ route('pekerjaans.download', $pekerjaans->id) }}"><u>{{$pekerjaans->status}}</u></a></td>
              <td>
                 
              </td>
              <td>
                
                
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
@endforeach
```

Here is how my page look like atm:
[image]